I can't access some website, DNS issue
I can't access to some websites (shadcn-vue.com, venge.io) using my Wifi network, But When I use mobile data then I can access, so it should be DNS problem.
First I tried to use Google's and Cloudflare's DNS like 8.8.8.8, 8.8.1.1, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1, I put it one of them into DNS input under IPV4 on WiFi settings.
First it seemed to work but then it's not working.
On chrome it shows QUIC protocol issue, then I disabled it, turned off WiFi router for 20 seconds then turned it on, relaunch the browser, but still didn't work.
Also tried other browsers like chromium, brave, firefox, zen, since problem was with DNS it didn't work too.
What can I do to fix that?

“It should be a dns issue.” How the heck have you concluded this? A firewall rule seems much more likely. Or another of the thousands of issues this might be. I highly doubt this is a dns issue.

Since I can reach those sites using Cloudflare DNS resolution, it's not the cause of the issue. As mentioned, your ISP could be blocking them, or some other issue. If a laptop, try using it in a library, cafe or other public access site. You might need to set DNS resolution to auto at some sites.

QUIC protocol issue isn't a DNS problem.

Those 2 sites have IPv6 addresses against them. Perhaps You have IPv6 configured, but it is not fully working.
